# adding multiple rows to jquery Datatables dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add multiple rows at once to a jQuery Datatable. I would like to be able to create a string such as the one below and call a function to add these elements as rows in the table. Is there a function that will allow me to do this?

```
var trString = "<tr class='custom class'><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class='custom class'><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class='custom class'><td></td><td></td></tr>"
```

I have seen the fnAddData function but I would not be able to add my custom classes dynamically to the rows using that function. Also I have tried fnAddTr but I keep receiving an error saying my object does not have the method "getElementsByTagName"

again, is there a function that will allow me to add a string of "" to a datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh I have found the solution here: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6092/fnaddtr-plugin-ntr.getelementsbytagname-is-not-a-function/p1

Answer (score 0):

You need scape quotes:

```
var trString = "<tr class=\"custom class\"><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class=\"custom class\"><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class=\"custom class\"><td></td><td></td></tr>";
```

Or:

```
var trString = '<tr class="custom class"><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class="custom class"><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class="custom class"><td></td><td></td></tr>';
```

Comment: sorry I should have written better example code.... It is correct in my application.

Comment: Its a bug? getelementsByTagName is getElementsByTagName, javascript is case censitive.